# Issue regarding running exe file and passing command line args c#

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

i have one c# console apps which expect some parameter when invoke exe file.

this is the code of my console apps. tell me is there any fault in code

```
using System.Drawing;
using net.sf.dotnetcli;

namespace GenerateTiles
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct OPTIONS
        {
            public const string FILEPATH = "f";
            public const string TARGETFOLDER = "t";
            public const string REMOVEXISTINGFILES = "d";
            public const string MAXZOOM = "max";
            public const string HELP = "help";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Options options = new Options();
            options.AddOption(new Option(OPTIONS.FILEPATH, true, "File to parse"));
            options.AddOption(new Option(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER, true, "Folder to create tiles"));
            options.AddOption(new Option(OPTIONS.REMOVEXISTINGFILES, false, "Remove existing files"));
            options.AddOption(new Option(OPTIONS.MAXZOOM, true, "Max zoom dimension"));
            options.AddOption(new Option(OPTIONS.HELP, true, "Print this message"));



            BasicParser parser = new BasicParser();
            CommandLine cmd = parser.Parse(options, args);

            if (cmd.HasOption(OPTIONS.HELP))
            {
                HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                formatter.PrintHelp("GenerateTiles", options);
                return;
            }

            //********


            //********

            if ((!cmd.HasOption(OPTIONS.FILEPATH)) ||
                (!cmd.HasOption(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER)) ||
                (!cmd.HasOption(OPTIONS.MAXZOOM)))
            {
                HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                formatter.PrintHelp("GenerateTiles", options);
                //return;
            }

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.FILEPATH)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("file not exist");
                return;
            }

            double maxZoom;
            bool res = double.TryParse(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.MAXZOOM), out maxZoom);
            if ((res == false) || (maxZoom >= 10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scale multiplier should be  an integer <=10");
                return;
            }

            //Read image                    
            Bitmap bmSource;
            try
            {
                bmSource = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.FILEPATH));
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("image file not valid");
                return;
            }

            //check directory exist
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER)))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER));
            }
            else if (cmd.HasOption(OPTIONS.REMOVEXISTINGFILES))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER));
                foreach (string file in files)
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file);

                string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER));
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                    System.IO.Directory.Delete(dir, true);
            }

            int actualHeight = bmSource.Height;
            int actualWidth = bmSource.Width;

            if (((actualHeight % 256) != 0)
                ||
                ((actualWidth % 256) != 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("image width and height pixels should be multiples of 256");
                return;
            }

            int actualResizeSizeWidth = 1;

            int level = 0;
            while (level <= maxZoom)
            {
                string leveldirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(cmd.GetOptionValue(OPTIONS.TARGETFOLDER), String.Format("{0}", level));
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(leveldirectory))
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(leveldirectory);

                int rowsInLevel = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, level));
                actualResizeSizeWidth = 256 * rowsInLevel;

                //create image to parse
                int actualResizeSizeHeight = (actualHeight * actualResizeSizeWidth) / actualWidth;
                Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bmSource, new Size(actualResizeSizeWidth, actualResizeSizeHeight));
                string levelSourceImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, "level.png");
                resized.Save(levelSourceImage);

                for (int x = 0; x < rowsInLevel; x++)
                {
                    string levelrowdirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, String.Format("{0}", x));
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(levelrowdirectory))
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(levelrowdirectory);

                    Bitmap bmLevelSource = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(levelSourceImage);

                    //generate tiles
                    int numberTilesHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(actualResizeSizeHeight / 256.0));
                    for (int y = 0; y < numberTilesHeight; y++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Generating Tiles  " + level.ToString() + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString()); int heightToCrop = actualResizeSizeHeight >= 256 ? 256 : actualResizeSizeHeight;
                        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(x * 256, y * 256, 256, heightToCrop);
                        //croped
                        Bitmap bmTile = bmLevelSource.Clone(destRect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
                        //full tile
                        Bitmap bmFullTile = new Bitmap(256, 256);
                        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmFullTile);
                        gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(bmTile, 0, 0);
                        bmFullTile.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(levelrowdirectory, String.Format("{0}.png", y)));
                        bmFullTile.Dispose();
                        bmTile.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                level++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am invoking the exe from command line with below argument

1) tried this way but failed

```
GenerateTiles /f C::\test\img.jpg /t C::\test\Src /max 10
```

2) tried again this way but failed

```
GenerateTiles /f C:\test\img.jpg /t C:\test\Src /max 10
```

3) tried again this way but failed

```
GenerateTiles C:\test\img.jpg C:\test\Src /max 10
```

so where i am making the mistake ? please rectify me. thanks

Comment: This may help [Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx)... It looks to me like you are complicating things a little too much. is an String array.

Comment: Where does `BasicParser` come from?  Also what specifically happens with each of your attempts?

Comment: the net.sf.dotnetcli which is off sourceforge.. however, this doesnt seem to parse the results in the code, it assigns the list options and the list of args, but doesnt seem to associate the two to having selected options.

Comment: i just like to know this way i am passing argument `C:\test\img.jpg C:\test\Src /max 10` what is wrong in it ?

Comment: tile generation logic http://www.stefangordon.com/simple-image-tiling-in-c/